# Grammar that generates a language with more "a" than "b"

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I need to find a grammar that generates the language composed by all words that have more $a$ than $b$ given an alphabet $\{a,b\}$

I tried the following production rules:

```
S->B
B->b | ABB | BAB | BAB | BBA
A->a
```

with this rules it's fairly simple to proof that all the words that the grammar generates are made up with more $a$ than $b$.

How can I proof that all words made up with more $a$ than $b$ can be generated that way?

Comment: You don't really need the $A \to a$ rule (you could just write the $B \to aBB$ for example. also you have $B \to BAB$ twice.

Comment: That set of production rules implements a grammar accepting more `b`s than `a`s, not vice versa. It's also rather redundant. You could just use the rule `S -> a | aS | bSS | SbS | SSb`.